# Need help with a hyperbola/parabola equation solving for an assignment

Tags: functions

Hi so i was given my Math C assignment today and the moment i looked at question 1 i knew i had no idea what to do. This is the graph i was given (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qdhL.jpg). I was asked to provide an equation for the curve however i don't understand how you can derive an equation of this because i have never seen anything like it. I thought that the equation would be something such as x=+/- |y^2| however this was just a guess after looking at it. Also there is another question which asks to show that the equation of the chord of PQ is given by (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnM6K.gif). And lastly, show that the equation of the tangent to the curve at a point corresponding to t, where t doesn't equal 0, is given by 2y-3tx+t^3=0

If anyone can help me or at least explain what i have to do i will be forever grateful!
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Is this a question about the *Mathematica* software? If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: oops sorry, its not to do with the software (i actually didnt know it was software) i was just trying to tag it as math which doesnt make sense to me now that i think about it. The only thing i have tried so far is plotting it parametrically on a graphing software (x=t^2 & y=t^3)

Answer (score 0):

1. From the diagram, the parameterised equations for the curve are:

$$x(t) = t^2,\quad y(t) = t^3.$$

To convert into rectangular coordinates, we combine these equations eliminating $t$. In this case, we have

$$x = t^2 = \left(y^{1/3}\right)^2 = y^{2/3}.$$

We could alternatively write this equation as either

$$y^2 = x^3\quad\text{or}\quad y=\pm x^{3/2}.$$

2. We are given two points and we need the equation of the line through them, so we use the two-point form for a line equation, as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
y-t_2^3 - \dfrac{t_1^3 - t_2^3}{t_1^2 - t_2^2}(x-t_2^2) &=& 0 \\
\left(t_1^2 - t_2^2\right)\left(y-t_2^3\right) - \left(t_1^3 - t_2^3\right) \left(x-t_2^2\right) &=& 0 \\
\left(t_1 - t_2\right)\left(t_1 + t_2\right)\left(y-t_2^3\right) - \left(t_1 - t_2\right)\left(t_1^2 + t_1t_2 + t_2^2\right) \left(x-t_2^2\right) &=& 0 \\
\left(t_1 + t_2\right)\left(y-t_2^3\right) - \left(t_1^2 + t_1t_2 + t_2^2\right) \left(x-t_2^2\right) &=& 0 \\
\left(t_1 + t_2\right)y - \left(t_1^2 + t_1t_2 + t_2^2\right)x + t_1^2t_2^2 &=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

3. To get the equation for a tangent to the curve at a point $t$, we firstly need the slope of the curve at that point. So we differentiate as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
y^2 &=& x^3 \\
2ydy &=& 3x^2dx \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &=& \dfrac{3x^2}{2y} \\
&=& \dfrac{3t^4}{2t^3}\qquad\text{substituting $x=t^2,\;y=t^3$} \\
&=& \dfrac{3t}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

So the equation of the tangent is $2y = 3tx + b\;$ for som $b$. Now, this line contains the point $\left(t^2,t^3\right)$, so

$$b = 2t^3 - 3t\times t^2 = -t^3.$$

Therefore, the equation of the tangent is:

$$2y - 3tx + t^3=0.$$